# Failed to compile llvm-6.0.0

Tags: build, cmake, llvm, gnu-make

llvm-6.0.0 failed, emitting the following errors suggesting that my compiler doesn't support generating unwind tables with exceptions disabled while it actually could.

```
Compiler doesn't support generation of unwind tables if exception support 
is disabled. Building libunwind DSO with runtime dependency on C++ ABI 
library is not supported.
```

I'm using clang-5.0 and clang++-5.0 provided by Debian 9 apt-get, and I tested them using options `-fno-exceptions
-funwind-tables` and they both returned no errors.

After googling, I found [[llvm-dev] Failed to configure LLVM for use with Musl](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-December/107774.html)
 which says using clang will work, but it doesn't on my machine.

I'm using

```
Linux version 4.9.0-6-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 
6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 
(2018-03-02)

clang version 5.0.1-svn327757-1~exp1~20180325230805.88 
(branches/release_50)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

My cmake options:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release                        \
  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-5.0                      \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++-5.0                  \
  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-O3"                             \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-O3"                           \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/llvm-6.0-2      \
  -DLLVM_BUILD_TOOLS=True                           \
  -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TOOLS=True                         \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_THREADS=True                        \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_PIC=True                            \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_CXX1Y=True                          \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=True                           \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_EH=True                             \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_LTO=Thin                            \
  -DLIBCXX_INSTALL_LIBRARY=True                     \
  -DLIBCXX_INSTALL_HEADERS=True                     \
  -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED=True                       \
  -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=False                  \
  -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_LIBRARY=True         \
  -DLIBCXX_INSTALL_EXPERIMENTAL_LIBRARY=True        \
  -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_FILESYSTEM=True                   \
  -DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI="libcxxabi"                      \
  -DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI_INCLUDE_PATHS=/usr/src/llvm-6.0/llvm-6.0.0/projects/libcxxabi/include \
  -DLIBCXXABI_USE_LLVM_UNWINDER=True                \
  -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_RTTI=True                         \
  -DLIBCXX_INCLUDE_BENCHMARKS=True                  \
  -DLIBCXX_BENCHMARK_NATIVE_STDLIB="libstdc++"      \
  -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm-6.0.0
```

Previously, I has succeeded in compiling without compiler-rt, libcxx and libunwind, and compiler option `-O3`.

Comment: Hope this helps: I made similar experiances. But I eventually succeeded compiling LLVM 6.0.0 and clang 6.0.0 together using g++ version 7.3 under Windows 7 and msys2. I used the mingw-w64-i686-toolchain. In msys2 64 bit console type `pacman -Ss gcc). I think LLVM 6.0.0 is just too new for debian and that for good reasons! After successfully compiling, I encounter many other small problems, even while trying to get a hello world project up and running. Using the latest and greatest can be very time consuming.

Comment: Next hope this helps: The next Ubuntu LTS is expected to be release this Month. It might come with a LLVM 6 package.